# algorithm for solving systems of linear Diophantine inequalities

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, diophantine

Is there a reasonably fast algorithm for solving systems of linear Diophantine inequalities?

Answer (score 0):

This [research paper](http://www.kcam.biz/contents/downLoad.php?idx=752) looks like something you'd like to read.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, except for one problem: They give the algorithm on pages 350-351, but part of step (3) appears to be missing.

Comment: Wow. Let me try to find the issue the algorithm came from, as that's pretty bad reviewing...

Comment: I'm not sure if you can view this PDF, but this paper seems to cover the same topics (solutions to the systems, but not for inequalities) so you might be able to find a use for it: http://www.springerlink.com/content/t8qa7gumcly3ua2m/

Comment: That might be able to help. I'm going to try reposting this question on math overflow. Maybe somebody there will have an idea.

Comment: I bet they'll just write you a research paper ;) That place is pretty hardcore.

Comment: Also, I'd try the Math Stackexchange site. I found it to be a lot more helpful that Mathoverflow, as the people there are very good at what they do: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I just ported an algorithm from www.numbertheory.org for doing this from PHP into to Python using either SymPy (arbitrary precision) or Numpy (faster but suffers from integer overflow), which you can find here https://github.com/tclose/Diophantine. It is reasonably fast depending on how large your system is.

I would recommend using the SymPy branch despite it being a little slow. If performance is a problem you could probably speed it up using the PyPy interpreter as it is written in pure python.